# Jodit WYSIWYG Buttons list changes when screen width changes

Tags: javascript, jodit

I`m using [Jodit WYSIWYG editor v.3](https://xdsoft.net/jodit/) in my project.

It is OK when option "buttons" changes - the list of buttons changes too. But it works only with max-screen size - when client screen size changes - the list of buttons changes too...

How to fix my "`buttons`" option for any screen width in Jodit WYSIWYG editor v.3?

[image: ok buttons]

[image: bad buttons]

Here in is my Jodit Options code:

```
var editor = new Jodit("#text-editor", {
      "toolbarSticky": false,
      "toolbarStickyOffset": 10,
      "showCharsCounter": false,
      "showWordsCounter": false,
      "showXPathInStatusbar": false,
      "buttons": "source,|,bold,strikethrough,underline,italic,|,ul,ol,outdent,indent,font,fontsize,brush,paragraph,|,image,video,table,link,|,align,undo,redo,hr,|,symbol,",
    });
```

Comment: you have to add  "buttonsMD" key to change it according to screen size. check their playground https://xdsoft.net/jodit/play.html?buttons=%2Cbold%2C%7C&buttonsMD=bold%2Cimage%2Cbrush%2Cparagraph%2C%2Calign%2C%7C%2Cundo%2Credo%2C%7C%2Ceraser%2Cdots&currentTab=Buttons

Comment: @bajran It works! But, do I really need to add all of screen sizes like MS, XL, SM, etc... and copy-paste whole buttons code? Like: "buttonsMD: ..."  "buttonsSM: ..." etc? Do Jodit have global options?

Comment: this is specified in their version 2.5.49 please check```Note. this is not the width of the device, the width of the editor
1]buttons The list of buttons that appear in the editor's toolbar on large places (≥ options.sizeLG).
2]buttonsMD The list of buttons that appear in the editor's toolbar on medium places (≥ options.sizeMD).
3]buttonsSM The list of buttons that appear in the editor's toolbar on small places (≥ options.sizeSM).
4]buttonsXS The list of buttons that appear in the editor's toolbar on extra small places (< options.sizeSM).```  https://xdsoft.net/jodit/v.2/doc/

Comment: @bajran Yep, I did it as you wrote. Works fine. Thank you!

Comment: if you find helpfull then please upvotes, so that it can help others also

Comment: @bajran How can I do it here - it`s only comments, not an answer. Do an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check the documentation to add the button according to screen size

[go to jodit](https://xdsoft.net/jodit/v.2/doc/)

**Version - 2.5.49
Note. this is not the width of the device, the width of the editor**

> 1]buttons The list of buttons that appear in the editor's toolbar on
>   large places (≥ options.sizeLG).  2]buttonsMD The list of buttons that
>   appear in the editor's toolbar on medium places (≥ options.sizeMD). 
>   3]buttonsSM The list of buttons that appear in the editor's toolbar on
>   small places (≥ options.sizeSM).  4]buttonsXS The list of buttons that
>   appear in the editor's toolbar on extra small places (<
>   options.sizeSM).